# mcookie and the never-ending random file generation

Tags: ls

Im running a VPS with CentOS. In the spirit of learning, Ive had some friends break a few things for me to fix. The one thing I am having trouble with at the moment is the following:

```
#alias ls='while true; do sleep 1; touch $(mcookie); done & disown; /bin/ls $LS_OPTIONS'
```

I'm not entirely sure what this was doing but I commented it out when I first noticed it in .bashrc
The issue is that it is creating empty files in any directory I ran ls on. I can delete them, no problem but they keep reappearing. I ran ps and grep'd for sleep 1 but the PID changes too often to kill. I tried to kill the PPID thinking this would help stop the creation of random empty file names in the file system but alas, it has not.

I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated. Not looking for a direct, just an arrow in the right direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I slayed the dragon!

I ran "ps fauxww" and grep'd for "sleep 1". Was able to find the PPID based of the results and just issued a kill -9 on those proceess ID's. Voila! No more random file generation based on mcookie.